# Removing groups of "000" from my file?

Tags: c++, binary, ifstream, decompiler, ofstream

In C++ I have made a program that exports to binary and now I am making a reader. It reads correctly, but there is only 1 issue. My file is a file that contains a set of numbers and when it is read and printed to the screen you see, 1470009300047000199. The sets of 3 "000" isn't supposed to be there. I loaded this file using an ifstream and plan to keep it that way. Can someone tell me how to remove the sets of "000" in my file? If I have to write another C++ program that does that I am fine with it, I just need something to remove the "000" and replace it with a space.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "Error 1";
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int FileLength;
        ifstream InputFile(argv[1], ios::binary);
        ofstream OutputFile("DECOMPILED_FILE.txt");
        InputFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
        FileLength = InputFile.tellg();
        InputFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        for (int i = 0; i < FileLength; i++)
        {
            cout << InputFile.get();
        }

        cin.get();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the zeros aren't present in your input file? If you're in some Unix, have you tried doing `hexdump <your file name here>`?

Comment: Yes I am sure they are not present in the original file. And no I am not using some Unix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a **regular expression** ? Try finding the substring `'000'` on the file, if found, replace it by " ".
Pseudocode:

```
for each line in the file do:
     if line.strstr("000") then
           line.replace("000", " ")

      cout << line << endl;
```

Comment: Sorry I am a bit of a noob. How do I get all the lines I wrote to the file and put them into a variable?

Comment: The main problem of doing what you said is that it's being read as a char and when you convert the chars to strings they get messed up and the program shutsdown.